# Create user-specific custom menus in Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I customize a custom menu in a bound script (to shared Sheets doc) per logged on user?  The security policies are completely blocking me from knowing who is logged on and using the Sheet. I need to restrict certain users from using certain custom functions.

Comment: Who owns the sheet?  What are the share settings for the users you need to restrict?  What security policies are blocking the script?  What is your code for checking who opened the sheet?

Comment: You cant do that while building the menu only while executing the menu item tou can validate the user

Answer (score 0):

If you can't know who is logged on, then you can't customize the menu.  So the real issue is configuring the settings to allow you to get the user.